# How to hide an app or a software from windows search in Windows 8.1?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, search, windows-search, hidden-file

I want to be able to hide a software/app, specifically 'Google Chrome' on my Windows 8.1 PC.
Upon searching for the app/software, I don't want chrome to show up in the search results. Is there a way to do it without renaming it?

For context, the following methods given in these links don't work for me -> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7e39ca/how-to-hide-apps-from-search-in-windows-8/ and https://www.groovypost.com/howto/pin-hide-windows-8-apps-search-bar/
because for some reason, upon right-clicking chrome, I don't find the hide option in the charms menu and there is no option to toggle app search to off in my PC Settings>Search.

Answer (score 0):

The installable version of Chrome will always be visible in the Start menu.

You will need to uninstall Chrome (save bookmarks) and install its portable
version in an unusual folder, meaning not
`C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`,
and create yourself a shortcut to `chrome.exe`.